# eclipse indigo can not install windowbuilder UI toolkit for SWT?

Tags: eclipse

Can you guys install it? I am not sure about whether that is a connectivity problem for me...
[image]

Comment: if you have same problem, try to install it from update site:"help">>"Install New Software">>"--All Available Sites--" try to find swt designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available for me. So check your connection. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem when installing via Window -> Preferences -> Window builder -> UI Toolkits.
However I succeeded installing (Swing toolkit) by first creating a new project and creating a new Swing User Interface.
This will also start the installer. This did work for me.